# Nevertheless after comma is good style?

Tags: punctuation, conjunctions

I have a question similar [to this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16976/using-and-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence), but it is actually the opposite.
I have been using always "nevertheless" after full stop, and today I felt to use it after comma. However, it looks really awkward to me, so that I would write a full stop.

Is it a right feeling or it is just because of my habit? 
Is it good style to use "nevertheless" after a comma?

If you could give me a general rule for punctuation before conjunctions, it would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, after you wake up from your coma.  Oh, you mean "comma".  I suppose you can put "nevertheless" after a comma.  Example:  Although he was afraid his parachute might not open, nevertheless he jumped.

Comment: Good to know, that it is "allowed". But to which extent is it good practice? For instance, in your example "nevertheless" sounds redundant. Could not we rather say: "Although he was afraid his parachute might not open, he jumped"? (thanks for correction coma -> comma ;))

Comment: I think I see what you mean.  "Nevertheless" in my sentence is a bit superfluous, but it's meant to emphasize that, even though he was afraid, he jumped.  In fact, writing "..., he jumped nevertheless" or "..., he jumped anyway" would likely be better.

Comment: A point of grammar; 'I felt to V ...' is probably [non-standard](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150601/can-you-say-feel-to-do-something/150632#150632).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth As you point out in your link, 'I felt to V ...' is a common expression in Christian milieus. I am sure I learned it there. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alan Cochrane, a competent writer, used one in [the Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1395739/Close-shave-that-ensured-success.html):

> - *He took a bit of persuading but he did it, nevertheless.*

This looks perfectly acceptable to me.

Note that this sense of *nevertheless* is synonymous with 'anyway' (though the comma would usually be dropped here). It is a 'sentence adverb' or what I'd call a 'pragmatic marker: class concessive/cancellative' (see [David Bell; Science Direct: Journal of Pragmatics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378216609003269)) usage.

From [Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nevertheless):> **nevertheless** [adverb]

> You use nevertheless when saying something that contrasts with what
> has just been said. [formal]
>
> - *His father, though ill-equipped for the
>   project, had nevertheless tried his best.*

Notice that the positioning of even a clause-modifying 'adverb' is quite fluid.

...................

But here:

- *He took a bit of persuading; nevertheless, he did it.*

a comma would not be heavy-duty enough. Two sentences are needed, or (as they will be semantically closely related) the equivalent use of a semicolon.

'Nevertheless' in this role is classed as a 'sentence connector' by some authorities (eg Collins) and as a 'conjunctive adverb' by others; it behaves differently from say 'but'.

[Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/semicolon/#:%7E:text=Use%20Semicolons%20With%20Conjunctive%20Adverbs,finally%2C%20likewise%2C%20and%20consequently.) [modified]  contains:

> 4. Use Semicolons With Conjunctive Adverbs
>
> When you have a conjunctive adverb linking two independent clauses,
> you should use a semicolon [before it]. Common conjunctive adverbs
> include *moreover, nevertheless, however, otherwise, therefore, then,
> finally, likewise*, and *consequently*.
>
> - *I needed to go for a walk and get some fresh air; also, I needed to buy milk.*
> - *Reports of the damage caused by the hurricane were greatly exaggerated; indeed, the storm was not a “hurricane” at all.*
> - *The students had been advised against walking alone at night; however, Cathy decided walking wasn’t dangerous if it was early in the
>   evening.*
> - *I’m not all that fond of the colors of tiger lilies; moreover, they don’t smell very good.*
>
> These words sometimes show up in other parts of a sentence; therefore,
> the semicolon rule only applies if it helps the conjunctive adverb
> join two independent clauses. This conjunctive adverb rule is similar
> to the conjunction rule. In both cases, check that the two ideas are
> independent clauses that could stand on their own as sentences. If so,
> then the semicolon is the correct choice.

Comment: +1 from me. Come back Edwin, I miss your style and class. You old curmudgeon, you.

Comment: Less of the _old_.

Comment: Thanks Edwin, my greatest concern was about using 'nevertheless' after a comma when it separates two sentences as a conjunctive adverb and you explained it quite clearly. You hit the mark!

Answer (score 1):

If you use “nevertheless” as an introductory word or if you use it in a way that interrupts the flow of a sentence (e.g. *I am, nevertheless, going.*), it definitely needs a comma after it (or surrounding it). However, if it comes at the end of a sentence, a comma isn’t at all necessary; it engenders a needless pause.

Answer (score 1):

'Nevertheless' is an adverb (a condensed temporal adverbial phrase) -- not a conjunction.  Therefore it can be used with commas, but it does not join clauses.  'However' is similar, but 'nevertheless' is always an adverb and its temporal quality makes the comma[s] optional if nothing follows it.